# How to sum every nth Column, based on criteria met in an adjacent column (Excel)

Tags: excel

I am using a '=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(COLUMN(' formula to sum every 5th column in my spreadsheet, and it works perfectly. I am now trying to add in some criteria, but the criteria is based on the adjacent column and not the column that I am summing.

Below is a snip of a simple example showing the type of data I am working with and what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

As you will see I am trying to sum 'F3' and every 5th column after that, but based on criteria being met in 'E3' and every 5th column after that.

This is the Formula I have used to sum every 5th Column:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(COLUMN(B3:P3)-COLUMN(F3),5)=0),(B3:P3))
```

But I am unsure how to incorporate the criteria (or if it is even possible).

Hopefully I have been clear enough, any questions please let me know.

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN($B3:$P3)-COLUMN($F3),5)=0)*($A3:$O3 = S$2),($B3:$P3))`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you so much for the quick response. Seems to be working just as needed. Appreciate it.